# Serialize Java object instance to JSON

Tags: java, json

How can I serialize an arbitrary instance of Java object into JSON? For example, I need to pass group of InetAdress

```
{
    "Client1":addr1
    "Client2":addr2
}
```

where `addr1` and `addr2` are instances of `InetAdress` class

Comment: Read the JSON docs at json.org.  It's a quite simple notation.  Anything that can be represented as Maps and Lists containing simple strings and numeric values will translate to JSON without additional coding.  Folks tend to make is more complicated than necessary by thinking they must serialize/deserialize other types of Java objects, when usually their needs are easily met with Maps and Lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson is a good library to de/serialize java objects to and from Json.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSON